# Using neo4j driver in js

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j

I am pretty new to js and making web applications, but i have helped to build a web app that uses ne04j. I am trying to use the neo4j driver now with BOLT to access the community edition.

I am trying to use url = 'bolt://localhost:7474'

But i cannot get it to work.

I was wondering if this is because I need to somehow link the neo4j driver to the js script and if anyone could let me know how to do this.

```
var url_ = 'bolt://localhost:7687' 
var pword = 'neo4j2' 
sigma.neo4j.getLabels(
            { url: url_, user: 'neo4j', password: pword },
            function (labels) {
                console.log(labels)
                NodeLabels = labels;
                console.log("NodeLabels: " + NodeLabels);
            }
    );
```

Thank you!

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, `7474` is the **http** port, not the bolt one. So you need to replace `bolt://localhost:7474` by `bolt://localhost:7687` or by `http://localhost:7474`.

The Sigma plugin for Neo4j only use the HTTP endpoint of Neo4j :

```
var url_ = 'http://localhost:7474' 
var pword = 'neo4j2' 
sigma.neo4j.getLabels(
  { url: url_, user: 'neo4j', password: pword },
  function (labels) {
    console.log(labels)
    NodeLabels = labels;
    console.log("NodeLabels: " + NodeLabels);
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have tried this but it still is not working.
Anymore ideas as to why?

Comment: Does the fact i am using sigma change anything?

Comment: basically i first start off by defining the url and pass word as a variable as below:

**var url_ = 'bolt://localhost:7687'
var pword = 'neo4j2'**

then i use this when I run queries through sigma, such as:

**sigma.neo4j.getLabels(
            { url: url_, user: 'neo4j', password: pword },
            function (labels) {
                console.log(labels)
                NodeLabels = labels;
                console.log("NodeLabels: " + NodeLabels);
            }
    );**

Comment: please, update your question with all the details ! In the mean time you can check this https://www.bsimard.com/2018/04/25/graph-viz-with-sigmajs.html

Comment: I have updated the question. Basically I think that i need to import the driver into my html or javascript, but i am not sure how that is done

Comment: Thank you, does this mean that you cannot use bolt with sigma? I am trying to set this up on a server and apparently bolt is what is needed.

Comment: This just mean that the plugin you are using does not implement `bolt`. If you want to sigma and bolt, click on the link that shared with you :)

Comment: I have been looking through it and it has very little info about bolt. All i can seem them doing is using the url 'bolt://localhost:7687' which is what we have been trying?

Comment: But everything is exaplined in the section `Create a graph structure from a Neo4j query`. And if you want more details, you can check this link : https://medium.com/neo4j/hands-on-graph-data-visualization-bd1f055a492d

Comment: you are too focus on the sigma neo4j connector and bolt. Like I said the neo4j sigma plugin can't be used with bolt (it's not implemented). But you can construct your graph structure for sigma with the official js driver like I explain it in the blog post

Comment: Ah ok i think i understand you now! thank you for your help. Means it will take a big rewrite of my code but very useful to know.